# Create custom keybinding to snap window

Tags: unity, gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, snap-windows

There is a shortcut to snap window to either half of the screen
<kbd>Ctrl + Super + Left</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl + Super + Right</kbd>. 
My first question is how this shortcut is defined in the system? All default shortcuts are defined in `gsettings` but this is not there.

Now coming to main question. Above shortcut snaps to half screen. I want the shortcut to snap it to 75%. How can I do this? And if I want to define a new shortcut to snap to 75%, then what will be the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make it work using `wmctrl` and `xdotool` . Both are window manipulation tool.

```
#!/bin/bash
WIN=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
eval $(xdotool getwindowgeometry --shell $WIN)
WIDTH=$(calc "int($WIDTH*0.75)")
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b remove,maximized_horz,sticky
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e "0,0,24,$WIDTH,-1"
```

Above script snap window to 75 % to its size to left side. Save above script in a file and assign shortcut to the file.

Similarly following script snap window to 25% width to the right.

```
#!/bin/bash
WIN=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
eval $(xdotool getwindowgeometry --shell $WIN)
X=$(calc "int($WIDTH-$WIDTH*0.25)")
WIDTH=$(calc "int($WIDTH*0.25)")
wmctrl -i -r $WINDOW -b remove,maximized_horz
wmctrl -i -r $WINDOW -e "0,$X,-1,$WIDTH,-1"
```

Check `wmctrl` and `xdotool` manpages and tutorials to find how they work.
Install dependencies using

```
sudo apt-get install apcalc wmctrl xdotool
```

Note: The resizing works relative to current window position and size. To make it relative to screen size, maximize the window then execute the script.

Comment: I must have missed the question, would definitely have posted. Note that your script resizes relative to the current *window* size, not the screen size.

Comment: @JacobVlijm, Thanks, I will edit the answer. In case you have different or better solution please post that. I had to try to get even this much workaround.